# How to look for different types of files in a directory?

Tags: c#, filesystems

```
public List<string> MapMyFiles()
{
    List<FileInfo> batchaddresses = new List<FileInfo>();
    foreach (object o in lstViewAddresses.Items)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(o.ToString(), "*-E.esy");
            files.ToList().ForEach(f => batchaddresses.Add(new FileInfo(f)));
        }
        catch
        {
            if(MessageBox.Show(o.ToString() + " does not exist. Process anyway?",
                       "Continue?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
                == DialogResult.Yes) { }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
    }

    return batchaddresses.OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime)
             .Select(f => f.FullName).ToList();
}
```

i would like to add to the array not only

> .ESY

but also

> "p-.csv"

how do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your code works for one set of wildcards...

Then after these lines:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(o.ToString(), "*-E.esy");
files.ToList().ForEach(f => batchaddresses.Add(new FileInfo(f)));
```

Add these:

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(o.ToString(), "*p-.csv");
files.ToList().ForEach(f => batchaddresses.Add(new FileInfo(f)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just include more filters and select them together:

```
var filters = new[] { "*-E.esy", "*p-.csv" };
var files = filters.SelectMany(f => Directory.GetFiles(o.ToString(), f));
// .. etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to iterate multiple times with different wildcards.

Comment: Create a `List<string>` and call `AddRange()` multiple times.

Comment: You already are appending, to a List, you just need to do it again with new arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<string> MapMyFiles()
{
    List<FileInfo> batchaddresses = new List<FileInfo>();
    foreach (object o in lstViewAddresses.Items)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(o);
        if (!di.Exists && MessageBox.Show(o.ToString() + " does not exist. Process anyway?", "Continue?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) != DialogResult.Yes)
            Application.Exit();

        (new List<string>(new[]{ "*-E.esy", "*p-.csv" })).ForEach(filter => {
            (new List<string>(di.GetFiles(filter))).ForEach(file => {
                batchaddresses.Add(new FileInfo(file));
            });
        });
    }

    return batchaddresses.OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime).Select(f => f.FullName).ToList();
}
```

There's my bid; added directory check as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try
 {
     foreach (string searchPattern in searchPatterns)
     {
         string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(o.ToString(), searchPattern);
         files.ToList().ForEach(f => batchaddresses.Add(new FileInfo(f)));
     }
 }
```